# Issue with full screen activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to make an app which has to full screen.No title bar,no action bar,nothing.Just app on the screen.

I have used different approaches

1.E.g adding these lines in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

2.Adding these in MainActivity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Non of these are working.My app crashes when i uses any of these codes.

Comment: post your crash logs!

Comment: Have you tried the official documentation on this topic? https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 1):

Full screen theme:

```
<style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

To hide navigation bar (API 19+):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

    // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
    // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
    // show up and won't hide
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(visibility -> {
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

Comment: Notification bar is now gone but soft keys are still there

Comment: @Junaid the code for hiding navigation bar works only on Android API 19+

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your style.xml

```
 <!-- No action and title bar -->
<style name="NoActionTitleBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionTitleBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    <!-- You might not need this tho -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

Add theme to your activity in your android manifest e.g check below

```
<activity
        android:name=".Launch"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionTitleBar">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code after setcontentview()

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Add below code into your style.xml file

```
<!--activity without actionbar-->
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Add theme for perticular activity into manifest file:

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

ex:

```
<activity
            android:name=".xyzActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```